# Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository in GitHub for Windows

Tags: github-for-windows

In GitHub for Windows, is there any way to ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository, aside from switching to the Git shell (`git rm --cached filename` to ignore, `git add filename` to undo ignore)?

Comment: You mean that you want to leave the pushed version of a file (or folder) in the repository, but stopping pushing the next changes?

Comment: @ChristianCavuti that's right

Answer (score 2):

Git can only ignore files that are untracked - files that haven't been committed to the repository, yet. That's why, when you create a new repository, you should also create a .gitignore file with all the file patterns you want to ignore.

How to make sure your files are ignored:

```
$ git rm -r --cached .
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Clean up ignored files"
```

For more information on how to ignore files: https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/ebook/en/command-line/basics/starting-with-an-unversioned-project#start